# I'm trying to find a module I played as a kid

Tags: published-adventures, adnd-1e, product-identification, dnd-becmi

What I remember is a dungeon crawl sort of module laid out as an inverted pyramid. There was art that depicted the builders vision of the souls travel to the afterlife.

At the apex of the pyramid, was the lair of the "boss monster". The art at the apex was supposed to depict the final step of the souls journey; but it has been defaced.

This would have been the early 80's, so AD&D 1e most likely. We were kids, it's definitely a possibility that this was an unlicensed module of some sort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some quick research: [B4 - *The Lost City*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_City_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)).

Was this it? It was published in '82.

> The lower tiers were to be a series of chambers showing the journey of the spirit after death. Each room was to have a painting of another stage in the journey. The final tier, where Zargon now lives, was to have a painting of the Cynidicean paradise. The painting was never made.

Comment: This is it. The parts I remember evidently aren't major parts of the module. Here's a quick excerpt from the module describing what I remember: 

“The lower tiers were to be a series of chambers showing the journey of the spirit after death. Each room was to have a painting of another stage in the journey. The final tier, where Zargon now lives, was to have a painting of the Cynidicean paradise. The painting was never made.”

Comment: @LeeMorgan Please avoid code formatting (backticks, four-space paragraph indents, `pre` tags) for non-code text. For quotations, quotation marks are the usual preference, though if you really insist bold or italics may be used. The issue with code formatting is that it can mess with the site’s accessibility, because non-visual browsing technology (i.e. screen readers for the blind) still have to treat it as “code” and that may make it rather difficult to read (e.g. it might be read out letter-by-letter in some cases). See [this meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3086/4563).

Comment: (Backticks in comment fixed.)

Comment: I was trying to remember this one a few weeks ago, but all that stuck with me was the pyramid, animatronic god statues (with speaking tubes) and a set of goblins dressed in bandages threatening the players reflected from a polished metal mirror, making it look like projectiles were having no effect on them since they were just hitting the mirror.